# Python Pandas DataFrame generating new column based on last n columns value

Tags: dataframe

Original Dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQDAw.png)
Outcome Rules:
Only the following scenarios will be marked as True:
Scenario 1: A1: True, A2: True
Scenario 2: A1: False, A2: True, B1: True, B2: True
Scenario 3: A1: False, A2: True, B1: False, B2: True, C1: True, C2: True

Please help here!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert your logics like the following. Ofcourse you need to make sure all those columns are of boolean types.

```
scen_1 = df['A1'] & df['A2']
scen_2 = ~df['A1'] & df['A2'] & df['B1'] & df['B2']
scen_3 = ~df['A1'] & df['A2'] & ~df['B1'] & df['C1'] & df['C2']

df['Outcome'] = scen_1 | scen_2 | scen_3
```